# Iterating for multiple for loops from API in Python

Tags: python, api

```py
self.flights_list = ApiConnector('airlabs', 'flights', 'dep_icao,arr_icao,flight_number,flag,aircraft_icao').get_data_from_api()
self.airports_list = ApiConnector('airlabs', 'airports', 'icao_code,name,lat,lng')

def get_airport_cordinates(self, airport_name):
       for i in self.airports_list.get_data_from_api():
           if(i.get('icao_code') == airport_name):               
               return i['lat'], i['lng']

def list_all_flights(self):
   for i in self.flights_list.get_data_from.api():
       if(i.get('dep_icao') and i.get('arr_icao')):
           print(f"Flight Number is {i['flight_number']} and the airline is {i['flag']} and the aircraft is {i['aircraft_icao']} going from {i['dep_icao']} to {i['arr_icao']}");
           print(f'Flight distance is {Emissions().calculate_distance(ApiResponse().get_airport_cordinates(i["dep_icao"]),  ApiResponse().get_airport_cordinates(i["arr_icao"]))} km');
           print(f'Flight CO2 emissions is {Emissions().calculate_co2_emissions(Emissions().calculate_distance(ApiResponse().get_airport_cordinates(i["dep_icao"]),  ApiResponse().get_airport_cordinates(i["arr_icao"])))} kg');
```

I am trying to iterate from Airlabs api. Basically two queries: one for flights, other for airports(which has latitude and longtitute - whic is extracted from iata_code from flights and match together however 2 responses have around 8mb but to iterate through all of them taking ages.
Is there any way how to speed it up ?

Speed up the for loops inside.

Generally

```
print(f"Flight Number is {i['flight_number']} and the airline is {i['flag']} and the aircraft is {i['aircraft_icao']} going from {i['dep_icao']} to {i['arr_icao']}");
```

-- this is working flawless (10000queries within a second)

However it slows down on this section.

```
print(f'Flight distance is {Emissions().calculate_distance(ApiResponse().get_airport_cordinates(i["dep_icao"]),  ApiResponse().get_airport_cordinates(i["arr_icao"]))} km'); --> which compares results from flight_list (around 8mb) to airports_list (around 2 mb), distance itself is relatively fast. Any guidance how to speed it up ?
```

Comment: Offtopic: I would suggest using `i.get('icao_code') == airport_name` instead of a try except block. `get()` returns `None` if the key is not found. (assuming that `self.airports_list` is a dictionary)

Comment: Thank you, that's the help I am looking for. yes it 's dictionary created from api_response.

Comment: I have changed it as suggested still not the speed I am looking for, perhaps (I am pretty sure) I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by moving static queries from API to the file :)

Comment: Can you elaborate?